# Warning: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given in /hermes/bosnacweb01/

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi I have an error message that appears on my site, someone can help me :
Warning: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given in /hermes/bosnacweb01/bosnacweb01ac/b1772/ipg.eafricartcom/e-africart.com/wp-content/plugins/yith-woocommerce-wishlist/includes/class.yith-wcwl.php on line 1156

```
        if( ! array_key_exists( $regex_paged, $rewrite_rules ) || ! array_key_exists( $regex_paged, $rewrite_rules ) ){
            flush_rewrite_rules();
        }
```

Comment: Please include the relevant parts of your code where the error occurs in your question, otherwise I doubt anyone will be able to help

Comment: if( ! array_key_exists( $regex_paged, $rewrite_rules ) || ! array_key_exists( $regex_paged, $rewrite_rules ) ){
             flush_rewrite_rules();
            }

Comment: Include the code in your question, please, not as a comment

Comment: It's says `$rewrite_rules` is not an array.

Comment: i have resolve my problem thank

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Look like you are having the same problem when updated the YITH WooCommerce Wishlist Plugin to version 2.1.1

I solved this by modifying the line 1156 to: `$rewrite_rules[] = get_option( 'rewrite_rules' );`

Hope this helped.